# Unable to increment value in a doctrine mongo query

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-mongodb

Looking at the example at: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html

I am unable to do a simple increment. That is the value of "votes" never changes. My document ID ($postID) is correct and I am able to fetch the document. Just unable to increment. Why is Mongo's documentation so out of whack??

```
$postID = "5121d0ad253b4af1d8000001";
 $dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
$post = $dm->createQueryBuilder('MainPostsBundle:Post')
->field('id')->equals($postID)
->field('votes')->inc(1)
->getQuery()->execute();
```

Comment: Try to add `->update()` juste after your `$dm->createQueryBuilder('MainPostsBundle:Post')`

Comment: that actually worked. However I really would have liked to be able to get a value of votes in the same statement. That is a update/select statement

Comment: What do you have in your `$post` ?

Comment: I checked that :)   It is a bool. The frustrating part is that the documentation gives you the assumption that you can do an update/select in one statement.

Comment: and that bool is true whether update goes through or not. Ha Ha

Comment: I'm not sure that all Database implementation (Mysql, PostGreSql...etc) support the UPDATE RETURNING value. But its not a shame to make a second query (select) juste after your update.

Answer (score 1):

findAndModify does both (see http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/find-and-update.html)